# G-invariant Tietze Extension Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, group-actions, quotient-spaces

The Tietze Extension Theorem states that if $V$ is a closed subset of a metric space $X$ and $f$ is a continuous function on $V$ then there exists $F$ continuous on $X$ such that $F|_{V} = f$.

Suppose that $G$ is a countable discrete group acting continuously on $X$ and that $f$ is $G$-invariant.  Does there exist $F$ continuous on all of $X$ which is also $G$-invariant such that $F|_{V} = f$?

The key step to prove it seems to be a $G$-invariant Urysohn Lemma: if $U$ and $V$ are closed subsets of $X$ which are $G$-invariant, does there exist a $G$-invariant continuous function such that $f^{-1}(U) = \{ 0 \}$ and $f^{-1}(V) = \{ 1 \}$?

Comment: Have you tried a concrete example? What if $X=\Bbb CP^1=S^2$, $U=\{0\}$, $V=\{\infty\}$, and $\Bbb Z$ acts by $z\mapsto z^n$? (Or take $\Bbb C$ and $V=\{1\}$.)

Comment: @TedShifrin This is a good point, that example shows it can't happen in general.  I wonder if there are stronger hypotheses on $U$ and $V$ that would make something like this true, for example if we knew that $d(U,V) < \epsilon$ could we get $f$ such that $|f(gx) - f(x)|<\epsilon$?

Comment: It seems to me that you need to address the topology of the orbit space $X/G$ and try to apply the Urysohn Lemma *there*.

Comment: @TedShifrin That makes sense, thanks for the idea.  I'll have to see what I can say about the quotient space in my specific context but at least that gives an avenue of attack which seems plausible.

Comment: By the way, you misstated Urysohn. For the preimage statement, you need $X/G$ to be completely normal, not just normal. Usually, it’s $f(U)=0$ and $f(V)=1$, but other stuff may map to $0$ and $1$.